# Hook QLineEdit showing text

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my problem.
I type some text into myLineEdit, for example "123456789 987654321", and I want to hide some substring in LineEdit, say "23" when displaying is hidden by another symbol "x". That's what i want to see "1x456789 987654321", but myLineEdit->text() must still return the correct string without replacements ("123456789 987654321").
So what what will help me to do this?

Comment: Create an inheritance class and implement there that kind of a behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be helpful. Instead of calling setText(QString) and text(), call setLineText(QString) and getText().

```
#include <qlineedit.h>
class LineEdit :public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
        LineEdit();
       ~LineEdit();
       QString hide_txt="23";
     void setLineText(QString txt) {
         txt.replace(hide_txt, "x");
         setText(txt);}
     QString getText() {
         QString txt = text();
         txt.replace("x", hide_txt);
         return txt;
     }

};
```

Comment: Does it work if the user enters the text using the GUI non-programmatically?

Comment: if the line edit is editable we have to use textChanged(const QString &text) signal and connect it to setLineText(QString)

Comment: and do not you think it generated an infinite loop? since according to your logic textChanged would call setLineText, and setLineText calls setText internally to call textChanged, textChanged would call setLineText and returned we will return to the beginning.

Comment: you are correct. we have to use textEdited(const QString &text) to avoid infinite loop instead of textChanged()